# Check for octal duplicates in array elements Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, octal

I have this loop that checks duplicate elements in an array. The problem is once the array has octal numbers the compiler throws an error. How do i make this work?

```
my @array1 = (010895401, 010895401, 010895402, 010895403); 

my %seen;

foreach my $octal (@array1)
{
    next unless $seen{$octal}++;
    print "'$octal' is duplicated.\n"
}
```

Comment: octal numbers with 8's and 9's in them don't make a lot of sense. What do you intend them to mean?

Comment: I just want to find the duplicate numbers in this array. I'm using `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php` to compile this code. It throws this error `Illegal octal digit '8' and '9' at main.pl line 1, at end of line`

Comment: the thing is you can't find duplicate numbers in the array because *those aren't numbers*.

Comment: If the array is an array *of numbers* then `010` (octal) is a duplicate of `8` (decimal). And also it's a duplicate of `0010` because extra leading zeros don't matter. And probably also a duplicate of `8.0` and `0.8e+1`. If you want string comparison, do as toolic says

Comment: I didn't know this wasn't numbers, but i still don't understand why they are not numbers. I looked at `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_arrays.htm` to write my this array.

Comment: They're not numbers because the digits aren't octal digits.

Comment: That tutorial is old and out-of-date. You should not use it. You can tell because it doesn't have `use strict` in the examples.

Comment: Thanks guys this is making more sense now :)

Comment: Check the Perl tag wiki here on SO for up to date tutorials. Hover your mouse over the tag below your question, then click the _info_ link, or use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info

Comment: Thanks @simbabque!

Comment: For future reference, your question should never say "the compiler throws an error."  Instead, it should give the exact error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It throws this error `Illegal octal digit '8' and '9' at main.pl line 1, at end of line`

A literal starting with `0` (other than those starting with `0x` or `0.`) is expected to be the octal representation of a number. The octal representation of numbers consists of digits 0-7 exclusively (similar to how the binary representation of numbers consists of the digits 0 and 1 exclusively).

As such, `010895401` is expected to be the octal representation of a number, but it isn't. `010895401` makes no sense.